# How to detect integer multiplication overflow in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

I'm writing code where I may run into a situation where an overflow may occur as a multiplication of two integers. As far as I tested, no exception is thrown anywhere.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I've looked at the C++ compiler options to check overflow but there's nothing about it. I have all the optimizations off, but still not getting an error while performing multiplication (which DOES result in overflow). I can't change some critical parts of my code, and I need a way to detect overflow, I know hardware will raise an exception in the case of an exception, but couln't get it working.

Comment: I am pretty sure that whoever told you that integer overflow raises an exception on x86 hardware was wrong.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c